# Calling function names from a slice and return a value

Tags: go

I want to call a number of function names stored in a slice. The code snippet below works so far but I need to return a value from those functions. Unfortunately I don't get it to work because I don't know to to call those functions and store the return value. Any ideas?

This is the code I'm currently working on:

```
package main

func A(x int) int {
    return x + 1
}

func B(x int) int {
    return x + 2
}

func C(x int) int {
    return x + 3
}

func main() {
    x := 10
    type fs func(x int) int

    f := []fs{A, B, C}

    fns := make([]func(), 3)

    for a, _ := range f {
        a := a
        fns[a] = func() {
            f[a](x)
        }
    }

    for _, f := range fns {
        f()
    }

}
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/n9Y31lW4lwL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have call it...

```golang
for a, _ := range f {
        a := a
        fns[a] = func() {
            f[a](x)        // in this
        }
    }
```

here is the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/e68U5V0db1H)